# offset marking in canvas.drawLine function

Tags: android

I am getting an offset while drawing lines using canvas.Drawline() function in android.
The function is as follows:

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        int action = motionEvent.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downx = motionEvent.getX();
                downy = motionEvent.getY();
                path.moveTo(downx, downy);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                upx = motionEvent.getX();
                upy = motionEvent.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                annotationImageView.invalidate();
                downx = upx;
                downy = upy;
                drawPoints.add(new Point(Math.round(upx) , Math.round(upy)));
                path.lineTo(upx, upy);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: the question is unclear. Can you be more specific with your query.

Comment: whenever i am trying to draw a line on the screen, there is a pixel offset and line is getting drawn somewhat 1cm left to the point where I am touching the screen.